# Storing a UNIX Timestamp in an Ant Property?

Tags: java, ant, timestamp

I'd like to store a UNIX timestamp (i.e. seconds since epoch) in an Ant property for later use in a couple build targets. It appears to be impossible:

```
<tstamp>
  <format property="build.time" />
</tstamp>`
```

...generates a formatted timestamp.

```
<propertyfile file="foo.properties">
    <entry key="build.time" type="date" default="now" />
</propertyfile>
```

...also generates a formatted timestamp.

I'd hope that this is possible without using `<exec>` or similar (since we will sometimes run the build on Windows).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google brings up:

http://www.norio.be/blog/2010/08/getting-unix-time-epoch-ant-build-file

```
<target name="print-epoch">
  <script language="javascript">
  <![CDATA[
    property = project.setProperty("now",Math.floor((new Date()).getTime()/1000));
  ]]>
  </script>
  <echo message="${now}" />
</target>
```

Other approaches that would be cleaner IMO would be to

1. create your own custom anttask. It's really not that difficult;
   http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html
2. Use the Maven exec plugin to execute Java to do this:
   http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I did plenty of Googling but I guess I didn't include "epoch" in my query. It still would be nice to do it without executing JavaScript, though.

Comment: Yeah, the other approach that would be cleaner IMO would be to create your own custom anttask. It's really not that difficult; http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html